# Magnet script for UNITY 3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, magnetometer, virtual-reality, google-cardboard

I'm working on a Google Cardboard project, right now i have a demo for Android where u can look around in a special scene i build in UNITY 3D, everything is working fine & looking good, but what I really want is:

I want to walk forward when I press the Google Cardboard magnet button.

I found a few script's on the web, but I do not know exactly how to make these scripts work in my UNITY project.

Can anybody help me further with this?

Comment: User CaseyB on GitHub posted a utility for this that uses Unity's event system- https://github.com/CaseyB/UnityCardboardTrigger/tree/develop

With this script on an object, the event OnCardboardTrigger() will run on other scrips attached to the same object when the button is pressed

Comment: Hey Agumander, thank you for you'r response! :) If i put the script on my FirstPersonController, what should i do then to make the controller move?

Comment: Put a function in your script called `OnCardboardTrigger()`, and inside that function you would put your movement control. As far as I can tell, this function would fire for every frame you have the button down so that movement control could be as simple as `transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed;`

Comment: Hey Agumander! I tried to do what u said, but i think it's still not working. My mobile doesn't give any sign of seeing the magnet.. even when i try Application.quit(); I putted the script from GitHub on my firstpersoncontroller, and added a script called: Button_press. Maybe i'm doing something extremely rong, i hope u could tell me then, gehehe..  [link] (http://www.nicoabbink.nl/screens/1.png) [/link] [link](http://www.nicoabbink.nl/screens/2.png) [/link]

Comment: hi.. i have done  set a single image in google cardboard vr surface.. and zoom in and zoom out process also.. i am working on head movement but not getting success.. if you have any idea then assist me.

Comment: Hi Nico, as far as I can tell the event system doesn't always for Javascript. If you write the Button Press script in C# it should work. You could also use JS if you make sure the Javascript is compiled *after* the Magnet Sensor script, but I couldn't say whether that's simple to do as I haven't tried it before.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are able to read the magnet input correctly. This is how I did an FPS style controller script:

1. In Unity5 import the asset package Standard Assets/Characters.
2. Create an instance of RigidBodyFPSController.prefab from that package.
3. Remove it's child object, "MainCamera"
4. Import the [Google cardboard unitypackage](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/unity/download).
5. Replace the "MainCamera" you removed in step #3 with CardboardMain.prefab
6. Update or modify a copy of RigidbodyFirstPersonController.cs GetInput() method.

GetInput() with Google Cardboard forward movement fallback:

```
private Vector2 GetInput()
{
    Vector2 input = new Vector2
    {
        x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"),
        y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical")
    };

    // If GetAxis are empty, try alternate input methods.
    if (Math.Abs(input.x) + Math.Abs(input.y) < 2 * float.Epsilon)
    {
        if (IsMoving) //IsMoving is the flag for forward movement. This is the bool that would be toggled by a click of the Google cardboard magnet
        {
            input = new Vector2(0, 1); // go straight forward by setting positive Vertical
        }
    }
    movementSettings.UpdateDesiredTargetSpeed(input);
    return input;
}
```

Google's SDK only support's detecting a magnet "click". If you want to hold down the magnet to move forward, I recommend using [Cardboard Controls+](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/25243) from the Unity3D Asset Store.

Comment: I dont have IsMoving flag. Says, it doesn't exist in the current context

Comment: On the line of code IsMoving is referenced above there is a code comment. This comment is used to explain that line of code. In this case, what would set the value of IsMoving. Where you scope in IsMoving is up to you, you could add a `public bool IsMoving;` on top of the block of code above.