# Automatically make First Person Controller run forward

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am making a game for Google Cardboard in Unity and I am using the First Person Controller object from Unity. It works fine with arrow keys but I would like it to automatically run forward at all times as I have no method of input on google cardboard.

I have little to no experience using unity currently but I know this is what I would like to do. Should I be modifying the script attached to the object?

Thanks

Comment: I have tried almost nothing, I've tried reading through the script and understanding how it works, but I cannot figure out where the actual input comes from. It;s as if I need the 'Up' key to be pressed permanantly.

Comment: The file you're looking for is *FPSInputController.js*. Search for *Input.GetAxis("Vertical")*. Replace it with *1*.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a copy of the answer I also used at [Magnet script for UNITY 3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26928904/magnet-script-for-unity-3d)

The only difference is you could replace "IsMoving" with "true" since you want your guy always moving forward. I did that replace here by just getting rid of the if block on my other answer:

1. In Unity5 import the asset package Standard Assets/Characters.
2. Create an instance of RigidBodyFPSController.prefab from that package.
3. Remove it's child object, "MainCamera"
4. Import the [Google cardboard unitypackage](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/unity/download).
5. Replace the "MainCamera" you removed in step #3 with CardboardMain.prefab
6. Update or modify a copy of RigidbodyFirstPersonController.cs GetInput() method.

GetInput() with Google Cardboard forward movement fallback:

```
private Vector2 GetInput()
{
    Vector2 input = new Vector2
    {
        x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"),
        y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical")
    };

    // If GetAxis are empty, try alternate input methods.
    if (Math.Abs(input.x) + Math.Abs(input.y) < 2 * float.Epsilon)
    {
        input = new Vector2(0, 1); // go straight forward by setting positive Vertical
    }
    movementSettings.UpdateDesiredTargetSpeed(input);
    return input;
}
```

Google's SDK only support's detecting a magnet "click". If you want to hold down the magnet to move forward, I recommend using [Cardboard Controls+](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/25243) from the Unity3D Asset Store.